# gam1 reviews migrate over to gam2, then disappear on app re-install

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We've seen cases like this:

Migrate a GAM1 domain to GAM2, the 'new' Gmail Gadget works fine for a couple days, then a few days later it stops showing for the entire domain.  The client re-installs the GAM2 app which triggers the Gmail gadget to show again, but unexpectedly their migrated product review is no longer visible.

We asked one client to re-check this and they reported back that **they can see the review from within their own account, but other marketplace users cannot see it.**

We can demonstrate this by confirming their domain is migrated then comparing the previous review in GAM1 with GAM2.  I can provide a couple examples privately.

Comment: Is this happening for just a single client, or all clients that you have migrated?

Comment: Are you more interested in the Gadget, or the GAM2 review behaviour? We noticed the GAM2 review issue on the first few clients we asked to re-install the app (to address the gadget), i.e. more than a single client. We've avoided asking clients re-install because of this observation.

Comment: Gotcha. Does the gadget keep disappearing every few days, even after a re-install? Does it happen for every customer you migrate?

Comment: It has not recurred after a re-install and happened to a small set of domains so far.

Comment: It's going to to be hard to troubleshoot in that case. The next time you see it happen, before they reinstall, send me the domain information (via private G+ message) and we can dive into the details.